# Are most women sexually aroused by videos of naked women?

Tags: medical-science, sexuality

I found this [article](https://www.mensjournal.com/health-fitness/are-all-women-bisexual-or-gay/) claims:

> 74 percent of women who identified as “**straight**” were strongly sexually aroused by both men and **women**

I found another claim from [Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/11977121/Women-are-either-bisexual-or-gay-but-never-straight.html) which is
most famous UK online version of the newspaper.

> A study has found that most women who say they are **straight** are in
>   fact aroused by videos of both naked men and **naked women**.

Comment: This feels more like an answer than a question.

Comment: @Rekesoft: It depends on the study, and whether it has been replicated. This could easily be an example of the Replication Crisis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis).

Comment: I believe this to be true but irrelevant--women tend to show **physical** arousal (but not mental) to seeing any sexual acts even if they have no desire to participate.  (Say, to video of animals copulating.)

Comment: I remember a study that found the same was true for men, i.e. that straight men seeing other men in sexually suggestive images caused them to get aroused.

Answer (score 17):

Results along these lines have been replicated in multiple studies. Here are quotes from the abstracts of a few relevant articles. Note that most but not all of these studies list [Gerulf Rieger](https://www.essex.ac.uk/people/riege57202/gerulf-rieger) as an author.

Published in [Psychological Science, 2004](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.0956-7976.2004.00750.x):

> Both heterosexual and homosexual women experienced strong genital arousal to both male and female sexual stimuli.

Published in [Biological Psychology, 2005](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301051105000323):

> Women showed [...] large increases in genital arousal to both human male and female stimuli.

Published in [PLoS ONE, 2012](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0040256):

> Among men, substantial dilation to both sexes was most common in bisexual-identified men. In contrast, among women, substantial dilation to both sexes was most common in heterosexual-identified women.

---

However, these studies should be viewed in the wider context of the literature. For an overview of that research, [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10508-009-9556-9) is a good place to start. To quote an especially relevant paragraph, note that the following seems to basically contradict the findings above:

> There is evidence of a gender difference in responses to specific sexual content. Still photographs of nude or partially clothed women or men do not generate either self-reported or genital sexual arousal in heterosexual women (Laan & Everaerd, 1995a, 1995b), but are sufficient to generate substantial subjective and genital responses in heterosexual men (Tollison, Adams, & Tollison, 1979). For men, depictions of affectionate, nonexplicit interactions (e.g., cuddling, kissing) between clothed women and men significantly increase subjective and genital responses but, for women, both significant arousal responses and null effects to these same stimuli have been reported (Suschinsky, Lalumière, & Chivers, 2009; Wincze, Venditti, Barlow, & Mavissakalian, 1980). More recently, we have found that both heterosexual and homosexual men, and homosexual women but not heterosexual women, showed genital responses to film depictions of their preferred sex engaged in nude, nonsexual activities, such as walking on the beach (Chivers, Seto, & Blanchard, 2007).